# How do I implement a dynamic type in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, types

I have an HTTP endpoint that is like "localhost://helloworld/Dogs" I want a dynamic way to extract the last part of this endpoint, in this case Dogs, and use it as a type in my method. Does anyone know how to do this?

In my code this is what I have so far

```
string className = ______ ; some code that extracts that entity as a string
var data = await myMethod.GetData<className>(id);
```

I get the error "className is a variable but it's used as a type. So then I try the following.

```
Type className = ______ ; some code that extracts that entity as a Type
var data = await myMethod.GetData<className>(id);
```

And I am still getting the error that says className is a variable but is used as a type. Any ideas?

Comment: Do not use the "Dogs" part to identify a type without validation and strict limitation. You could open yourself to some sort of injection vulnerability that allows the client to instantiate an arbitrary type, and who-knows-what from there.